# Add URL as a value in neo4j node

Tags: url, import, neo4j

I want to create a node in Neo4j with 'url' as its value (which contains more special characters)

This is My sample input csv

#

Attrid:ID,URL

Accenture,https://www.example.com/sg-en/company-leadership-team.aspx

Yeos,http://www.example.org.sg/2012-iaaf-world-indoor-championships-gary

#

When I tried importing using neo4j-import, I got "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException".

I tried escaping special characters using '\'. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you tried wrap URL in quotes? Example: “http://www.example.org.sg/2012-iaaf-world-indoor-championships-gary"

Comment: I tried wrapping the url in double quotes. It doesn't help me. Please note am using neo4j-import. It may make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load those lines using `load csv` in the browser. If sample.csv contains this...

```
ID,URL
Accenture,https://www.example.com/sg-en/company-leadership-team.aspx
Yeos,http://www.example.org.sg/2012-iaaf-world-indoor-championships-gary
```

Then a statement like this should load the attributes as-is

```
load csv with headers
from 'file:/sample.csv'
as row
create (n:Node {id: row.ID, url: row.URL})
return *
```

Comment: I am glad it worked. But As I mentioned I was using command line tool 'neo4j-import' to import the CSVs. Is it possible there ? Also how can I avoid creating node for duplicates entries in my input if I use 'load csv' tool.